# Redux Form - Not able to type anything in input

Tags: redux-form

Hi I have upgraded to redux-form version 6.0.0 recently. And I am facing an issue like I am not able to type anything in the text field.

P.S I am also using Reactintl. I am using compose to aggregate connect, reduxform and intl decorator

Here is my code 
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dwfDRJLg)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, then starting with v6 you should provide extra *onBlur* and *onChange* methods for the input in order to update its state. For your stateless component *renderInput* it could be done like this:

```
const renderInput = (field) => {

  const onBlur = () => {
    field.input.onBlur(field.input.value);
  };

  const onChange = (inputValue) => {
    field.input.onChange(inputValue ? inputValue : '')
  };

  return <input {...field.input} onBlur={onBlur} onChange={onChange}
                [...other options omitted for readability] /> 

}
```

Comment: If there's `field.input.onChange` then it's effectively propagated to the input component in `{...field.input}` and so there's no need to propagate it additionally with `onChange={onChange}`. Your example thus has no effect apart from adding an additional hop in the call to `field.input.onChange`.