# Unable to type anything in the input component in the Redux form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am playing around redux forms. I am in a scenario where i am unable to type a value in the input field attached. Whatever i am trying to type , The cursor is still at the starting point.

My question is kind of similar to : [Redux Form - Not able to type anything in input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39326454/redux-form-not-able-to-type-anything-in-input)

Attached is my code.

Login.js:

```
 import React,{ Component } from 'react';
 import  { Field, reduxForm, Form } from 'redux-form';

 class Login extends Component {

     handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
     //handling login data.
     console.log('hi');
     console.log(e);
 };


 render() {
     //  console.log(this.props);
    console.log(this.props);
    const {handleSubmit, fields:{email}} = this.props;

  return (
      <Form onSubmit ={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>

       <fieldset className="form-group">
       <label>Email:</label>
       <Field name="email" component="input" type="text"      
        className="form-control" {...email}/>
      </fieldset>

      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
       SignIn
     </button>
    </Form>
);
}
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'LoginForm',
  fields: ['email']
  })(Login);
```

Attached is my package.json

[image]

Attached is my scenario:
[image]

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any errors? And what this object contains `{...email}`?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `v5` and `v6` usage.

Get rid of the `email` variable in your `render()` method, and you should be okay.